# wordpress php hardcode item to submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

I'm trying to add an item to a sub menu via functions.php as the item will change based on the users logged in status and subscription status.

Here is the code I use to add an item to the menu:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li>Show whatever</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

However, does anyone know how I would add an item to a submenu?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **add_menu_subpage** wordpress' function.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
          null   //or 'options.php' 
          , 'My Custom Submenu Page' 
          , 'My Custom Submenu Page'
          , 'manage_options'
          , 'my-custom-submenu-page'
          , 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback'
    );

}
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Comment: OP asking to add items to WordPress menu not admin menu.